# Bash in-place replacement of text

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have some insert statements which I want to transform for another environment by replacing values in place. My sql insert statement looks like below:-

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('1', '/var/tmp', 'xyz, mno, pqr', '123', '<dummy value>');
```

I want to convert it such that there are no spaces left between column and values between () which would look like this:-

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) VALUES ('1','/var/tmp','xyz,mno,pqr','123','<dummy value>');
```

What I have tried so far is something like this:-

```
echo "INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('1', '/var/tmp', 'xyz, mno, pqr', '123', '<dummy value>')" | awk -F'[()]' '{printf "%s(%s)%s(%s)", $1, $2, $3, gensub(".*\(","",gensub(" ", "", $4))}'
```

And the resulting output is as below:-

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('1', '/var/tmp', 'xyz, mno, pqr', '123', '<dummy value>'))
```

I am stuck here. Any cues would be helpful.

Comment: Why not something like `sed -E 's/, /,/g'`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I don't know if the spaces would be leading or trailing or in between the single quotes.

Comment: `sed` works with regexes, replace with a simple one and you're done. Give it a try.

Comment: `sed -E 's/ *, */,/g'`

Comment: @MarounMaroun, I tried that but I don't know how to mix sed with awk. Since I don't want to remove whitespace selectively from the string, I am not getting a fruitful result.

Comment: @MarounMaroun You may post that as an answer. :-) That should solve ops issue

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to do this? I expect any database system to just ignore these spaces. Replacing them looks completely pointless, queries should work just fine with or without such spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can have much simpler solution using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/, /,/g'
```

If you're not sure about the comma's position, you can use a regex (see [@anubhava comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615832/bash-in-place-replacement-of-text/47615967#comment82190004_47615832)):

```
sed -E 's/ *, */,/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "(1, 2, 3) and (4 ,5 ,6)" | sed -E 's/ *, */,/g'
(1,2,3) and (4,5,6)
```

Comment: Op should note that use of `g` flag is important here as it does the global replacement.

Comment: Also, the `-E` flag might not be documented in newer version of sed manual but it there for compatibility reasons and it is meant for using the extended regex. Though, I don't see that it is made to proper use as far as this example is concerned.